# Can not deserialize instance of my.package.name.PlaceData[] out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, parsing, deserialization

I have been trying to deserialize a json stirng. Do not understand where is the problem. It is throwing-

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of my.package.name.PlaceData[] out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1fea1293; line: 1, column: 1]
```

My JSON string (placesData) is

```
    {
      "d":[
        {
          "__type":"my.package.name.PlaceData",
          "Id":1212,
          "Name":"Delhi",
          "MeetingId":1211,
          "Sessions":[]
        },
        {
          "__type":"my.package.name.PlaceData",
          "Id":8787,
          "Name":"Bangalore",
          "MeetingId":1211,
          "SessionNames":[]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Java object is-

```
public class PlaceData  {
    public String __type;
    public Integer Id;
    public String Name;
    public Integer MeetingId;
    public SessionData[] sessionData=new SessionData[0];

    public PlaceData() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PlaceData{" +
                "__type='" + __type + '\'' +
                ", Id=" + Id +
                ", Name='" + Name + '\'' +
                ", MeetingId=" + MeetingId +
                ", SessionData=" + Arrays.toString(SessionData) +
                '}';
    } }
```

Deserialization code-

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<PlaceData> placesList = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(placesData, PlaceData[].class));
```

Any clue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're deserializing an object rather than an array.  The START_OBJECT token refers to the opening { bracket.  You're actual data is accessible from propert 'd' of that object.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Could you please describe a bit more. How can the given json be deserialized?

Comment: Try deserializing to Map<String, List<PlaceData>> and then getting your list with map.get("d")

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It worked.  I added it as - `TypeReference<HashMap<String,PlaceData[]>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,PlaceData[]>>(){};</br>
HashMap<String,Object> response = mapper.readValue(placesData, typeRef);`